# Peak current limit and valley current limit of inverting buck-boost converter

Tags: buck-boost

I am trying to understand, in a inverting buck-boost converter, why the peak current in the inductor should be smaller than the high-side current limit and valley current in the inductor should be smaller than the low-side current limit.

My understanding:
[image]

During high-side switch ON and low-side switch OFF, the current goes up until peak current and during low-side switch ON and high-side switch OFF the current goes down. So this peak current should be smaller than both low-side current limit or high-side current limit, whichever is smaller. But when I read [this artical](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva856b/snva856b.pdf?ts=1701248252818&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) for TI (page 14), it seems it's just OK if Ipeak < high-side current limit (4.2A<4.8A) and Ivalley < low-side current limit (3.7A<3.9A). So why? During low-side switch ON and high-side switch OFF, the current passing throug low-side MOSFET goes down from Ipeak to Ivalley, so if Ipeak > low-side current limit (4.2A > 3.9A), it shouldn't work!

Can anyone explai it?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *current limit* (both instances)?

Comment: It's from the datasheet of LMR33640 : (page 6) 
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr33640.pdf?ts=1701250417628&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F  where shows the current limit

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. In TI's document (Page 14) they give an example for how to choose a proper buck converter to convert it to an inverting buck-boost converter by comparing the calculated current limit and the current limit of a chosen buck convertor (LMR33640). I just don't understand why in that case they choose a buck converter whose low-side current limit is smaller than peak current (3.9A<4.2A).

Comment: See my answer Mr. X

Comment: The word "inverting" doesn't appear in that document at all and neither does it state a current of 4.2 amps (CTRL-F search words)

Comment: The technical document that I read is in my original question : "But when I read this artical for TI (page 14), it seems..."   or the link: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva856b/snva856b.pdf?ts=1701248252818&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: So, what's the issue now? My answer shows that the internal current limiting on the valley MOSFET can be as high as 5 amps. Of course, if you want a reliable design you shouldn't design the circuit current to be greater than 3.9 amps but, you can't stop folk trying that and making it work in many occasions.

Comment: Hi, I just tried to answer your previous question about word "inverting", the statement of 4.2A., etc... I appreciate your answer. Thanks

Comment: OK, thank you. I see the other link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *so if Ipeak > low-side current limit (4.2A > 3.9A), it shouldn't work!*

You haven't read the information on page 6 correctly: -

[image]

The typical current limit value for the high-side is 5.5 amps but, could be as high as 6.2 amps. For the low-side the current limit could be as high as 5 amps or as low as 3.9 amps and, 4.2 amps seems reasonable to me and within data sheet expectations.